# Como pasarle dos generics a mi función

Tags: c#

Necesito crear un método para reutilizar en todos mis controladores al momento de hacer llamadas hacia una api, mi método seria `async` y de tipo `Task<>`.

Ejemplo: El siguiente método realiza un `request` hacia una api en donde le paso como parámetro una ruta `path` y un modelo en `<T>` al llamar al método.

```
public static async Task<Object> GetAsync<T>(string path)
{
    T obj = default(T);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await ClientService.GenerateClient().GetAsync(path);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        obj = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
        return obj;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageViewModel msg = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MessageViewModel>();
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Lo llamo de la siguiente forma en mis controladores.

```
await ... GetAsync<MiModelo1>("api/miruta");
```

Todo bien hasta ahí, el modelo `MiModelo1` seria el modelo donde guardara el `response` en caso de ser exitoso el `request`, que seria equivalente a lo que esta dentro del `if`. Pero no hayo la forma de poder pasar otro modelo diatónicamente como el anterior, desde la llamada del método quizás algo así... `await ... GetAsync<MiModelo1, MiModelo2>("api/miruta")` para poder ocupar ese modelo `MiModelo2` en el bloque de mi `else` para que en caso de dar un error me capture los errores en un modelo que yo quiera.

No se si me explique bien, en cuento corto necesito crear un método para hacer llamadas a una api de tipo GET y poder reutilizarlo en todos mis controladores, para evitar duplicar tanto código.

Finalmente lo que espero tener seria algo asi...

```
public static async Task<Object> GetAsync<T, T>(string path)
{
    T obj = default(T);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await ClientService.GenerateClient().GetAsync(path);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        obj = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>(); // Este T equivale al modelo MiModelo1
        return obj;
    }
    else
    {
        msg = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>(); // Este T equivale al modelo MiModelo2
        return msg;
    }
}
```

En donde `GetAsync<T, T>` cada `T` seria `MiModelo1` y `MiModelo2` y al llamarlo desde mi `controller` poder pasarle 2 modelos junto con la ruta. `await ... GetAsync<MiModelo1, MiModelo2>("api/miruta")`

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar en esto, gracias.

Comment: No comprendo bien tu  pregunta. Dices que quieres reutilizar el metodo pero luego mencionas el asunto sobre los parametros genericos. Pudieras organizar tu idea?

Comment: La idea es la misma que plantee... Tengo un método que consume una api al cual le paso un modelo y una ruta de la siguiente forma `GetAsync<Modelo1>("ruta")` el `Modelo1` lo utilizo para almacenar el `response` del `request` en caso de ser exitoso, pero en caso contrario de tener algun error en el `request` necesito almacenar esos errores en otro modelo, por ejemplo Modelo2, Modelo3, Modelo4. etc... El tema es que necesito poder pasar un modelo mas como parámetro a mi llamada y poder manejarlo dentro de mi 'funcion' reutilizable para consumir la api.

Comment: @gbianchi este método que utilizo lo tengo en un archivo de clase, al cual lo llamo desde mis controladores, y el método funciona todo bien pero no se como poder pasarle o que reciba dos modelos de la forma `GetAsync<T, P>(string path)` donde `T` seria Modelo1 y `P` seria Modelo2 u otro

Comment: @gbianchi No funciona...

Comment: Creo que me confundí con esa `P` que seria la `P`? se comporta de la misma forma que `T`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas confundiendo un concepto. Cuando defines la función como `public static async Task<Object> GetAsync<T>`, esa T es solamente un placeholder (un contenedor) para un atributo de tipo generico, que va a ser definido luego por quien llama a esa función.

Asi como usas T, podria llamarse P, V, M o Estoesungenerico.

Asi, para definir la función, solo necesitas hacer:

```
public static async Task<Object> GetAsync<T,P>
```

Donde T sera el primer tipo de objeto que vas a usar, y P el segundo. Tambien podrian llamarse Tipo1 y Tipo2

```
public static async Task<Object> GetAsync<Tipo1,Tipo2>
```

Para llamar a esa funcion basta que hagas:

```
GetAsync<int,string> //o los tipos que vos quieras
```

Dentro de la funcion, Tipo1 y Tipo2 definen a los tipos de retorno en tu caso. no es necesario que hagas:

```
Tipo1 obj = default(Tipo1);
```

Ya que no aporta nada. Basta que hagas en el return el cast directo.

```
return ((Tipo1)await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Tipo1>());
```

Es muy importante que leas y entiendas como funciona generics. Por favor, lee con atencion [este link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

Comment: Genial, esto me sirvió. Echare un vistazo a la documentación que me dejaste. Solo una duda, no se pueden repetir dos `T` cierto? por que era así como lo tenia yo y me daba un error.

Comment: T es solo un nombre, no significa nada..

Comment: T viene de Type...

Comment: para mas info, viene exactamente de la convencion de nombres a usar para los genericos. Ver [aca](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters#type-parameter-naming-guidelines)